# MathOverflow 2.0 is a-comin'!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, mathoverflow

Not a question; more of a notification.  For those who are unaware, [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) is upgrading to the "new" StackExchange platform.

A recent update on [meta.mathoverflow.net](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/):

> Anton Geraschenko 3 days ago
>
> Quick update: the incorporation of MO is underway. Unless there are
>   any other surprises, this means we should be migrating within a couple
>   of weeks! Once we've confirmed that there aren't any surprises, we'll
>   post a banner on the main site so that everybody has some advanced
>   notice in the days leading up to the migration.

Personally, I think it'll be great for non-research-level (but otherwise perfectly good) questions on MathOverflow to be able to be migrated here.

Comment: Good news, of course. But being named *MathOverflow* in the footer of the SE sites may cause some problems for them... SE users will likely interpret it as "like *StackOverflow*, but for math": that is, math questions at all levels. But the correct parallel would be *StackOverflow* $\approx$ *Mathematics* and *Programmers* $\approx$ *MathOverflow*. Hm, maybe it's not too late to rename the site as *Mathematicians*...

Comment: Related: [What, when and will we migrate questions to MO 2.0?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4880/75064) (Warning: rated R for hard language, intense or persistent debate, verbal abuse or other elements).

Comment: @75064: I don't know how you've gotten the impression that *Programmers* $\approx$ *MathOverflow*, but that is incorrect. MathOverflow is primarily for research-level **mathematics**, not discussion by professional mathematicians of conceptual questions about mathematics (though that does occasionally happen too). [I think a much better analogy would be with *Theoretical Computer Science*](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/235/7773).

Comment: @Zev Good point. Then *Theoretical Mathematics* could be a more precise title... theoretically, that is. I guess the name of MO is sufficiently entrenched that migration won't change it, possible misconceptions notwithstanding.

Comment: @75064: I don't know how "incorporated" MO is going to be into the whole network. It might be somewhat isolated from the rest of the sites, and in any case the title "MathOverflow" is going to remain. I'm not sure that the "stackexchange" suffix is going to be added here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I presume they will keep `mathoverflow.net`, like `askubuntu.com` kept their domain after migrating to SE 2.0. But this is only a cosmetic difference. ¶ I guess not being listed in the footer would solve the problem of clueless SE users wading over.

Comment: @75064: That's what I meant when I said that MO might be separate from the rest of the network. To my understanding there has been a legal document written and signed by the relevant parties which describes the transfer of MO to the SE network, and it may or may not include such clauses.

Comment: I'm hoping that the MathOverflow and math.SE accounts can be linked somehow.  (Hopefully they are at least that incorporated.)

Comment: When MathOverflow comes to the StackExchange network, do we get 100 reputation there too ?

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones Maybe a silly question, but why are there two seperate Maths platforms, namely MSE & MathsOverflow?

Comment: @Thomas [Differences between mathoverflow and math.stackexchange.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/41/differences-between-mathoverflow-and-math-stackexchange)

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who stumbles upon this in a Google search:

[MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) has now been fully incorporated into the SE network.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10067/i-found-mo-has-been-included-in-se-network-today

Comment: You will be assimilated...you will be assimilated...

Answer (score -4):

It could be good to ask the MO administrators about creating a second meta.mathoverflow.net site as an unofficial external discussion space for MSE.  Or use the existing one by adding some categories to it.

Votes and comments and complex display capabilities were built for the SE main sites but have the frequently realized potential to turn the meta.MSE conversations into a disaster.  The more primitive meta.mathoverflow interface does not promote the same behaviors.

Comment: well, tell Anton and Scott when possible. For me, both MO and MO Meta are currently down. 15:50 Pacific

Comment: @zyx That seems unlikely to happen, considering Anton's post that started the linked meta.MO thread: "I've become increasingly of the opinion that a pure SE-style meta is the way to go. While our discussion-style meta was certainly invaluable for hashing out community norms, I don't think there was anything in the last year that wouldn't have been well-served by an SE-style meta. Not only that, there would have been a huge benefit: proper integration with the main site."